# How to redirect to localized route in node.js express

Tags: node.js, angular, express, localization, internationalization

I'm using the official i18n library to localize my Angular Universal app and am using a proxy to serve the localized versions.

My app works fine as long as there is a language present in the url (e.g: /en/page), but doesn't work otherwise (e.g: / or /page). I get the error `Cannot GET /` whenever I try to access a page without the locale in the url.

How do I redirect the user to the localized version of the page using the `accept-language` header of the request? If I try it with the code below, it creates a redirect loop and the page doesn't load.

### server.run.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

function app() {
  const server = express();

  server.use(cookieParser());

  server.use('/', (req, res, next) => {
    const languages = ['en', 'de', 'fr'];

    languages.forEach((locale) => {
      const appServerModule = require(path.join(__dirname, locale, 'main.js'));
      server.use(`/${locale}`, appServerModule.app(locale));
    });

    locale = (req.headers['accept-language'] || '').substring(0, 2);

    if (!languages.includes(locale)) {
      locale = 'en';
    }

    res.redirect(`/${locale}`)
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  app().listen(4200, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4200`);
  });
}

run();
```

Comment: try to put languages handlers registration  out of '/' handler

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

function app() {
  const server = express();

  server.use(cookieParser());

  const languages = ['en', 'de', 'fr'];

  languages.forEach((locale) => {
    const appServerModule = require(path.join(__dirname, locale, 'main.js'));
    server.use(`/${locale}`, appServerModule.app(locale));
  });

  server.get('/(:locale(en|fr|de)/)?*', (req, res, next) => {
    const { urlLocale } = req.params;
    const userLocale = (req.headers['accept-language'] || '').substring(0, 2);

    if (urlLocale !== userLocale) {
      res.redirect(userLocale + req.url);
    }
  });

  return server;
}

function run() {
  app().listen(4200, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:4200`);
  });
}

run();
```